# What's a good way to create quasi-3d blocks in CSS?

Tags: css, 3d

Here's an example as an image:

[image]

I want to style page elements like this using CSS, though.  I can't seem to get it to work with border styles.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://cubiq.org/building-a-pure-css-3d-city

Comment: +1 ...and CSS does yet another thing I didn't think it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do it with two skewed pseudo-elements. [Support is the same as for `box-shadow`: everything except IE8/7 and Opera Mini](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

## [*live demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/4576160)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='box'></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10em auto 0;
    width: 20em; height: 20em;
    background: dimgrey;
}
.box:before, .box:after {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    content: '';
}
.box:before {
    top: 0; right: 100%; bottom: 0;
    width: 4em;
    background: darkgrey;
    transform: skewY(45deg);
}
.box:after {
    right: 0; bottom: 100%; left: 0;
    height: 4em;
    background: silver;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}
```